# Error en conexion SQL : java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora est. Pacífico, Sudaméric' is unrecognized or represents one time zone

Tags: java, mysql

Comunidad, tengo la siguiente excepcion al momento de realizar la conexion a la base de datos mysql desde java.

Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
jun 03, 2020 5:28:04 PM utils.UtilRecoleccion cargarloteActualTransacciones
GRAVE: null
java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora est. Pacífico, Sudaméric' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Gracias de antemano por sus comentarios

Saludos Cordiales
Fabian

Answer (score 1):

A pesar de que la traza de error no se vea demasiado bien y que no añades código para tratar de ayudarte, a simple vista veo dos cosas:

1. com.mysql.jdbc.Driver está obsoleto(deprecated) utiliza com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver en su lugar.
2. En la URL de conexión con tu base de datos, debes especificar la zona horaria.

   jdbc:mysql://***tudireccion***:***tupuerto***/***tubasededatos***?serverTimezone=***tuzonahoraria***

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar el error que indica en la pregunta, yo lo solucioné agregando los siguientes atributos en la ruta de conexión:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```